# The with binding in knockout has different behavior for comment/less binding

Tags: knockout.js

approach 1: **FAILS**

```
<div>number:</div>
<div data-bind="with: Selected().alarmtime"></div>
```

Result is:

essage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'alarmtime' of null;
Bindings value: with: Selected().alarmtime Error {}

approach 2: **SUCCEEDS**

```
<!-- ko with: Selected() -->
<div data-bind="text: alarmtime"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Why the difference behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case knockout tries to evaluate full expression - `Selected().alarmtime`, at that time `Selected()` is null. So `ko` tries to find `alarmtime` property in `null` that leads to the error.

In the second case `ko` evaluated only `Selected()` expression which equals to `null` so `ko` doesn't render div and doesn't try to evaluate `Selected().alarmtime`.